# Why data list option is holding a strong tag when it is not in the standard?

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

We can see the standard covered here, Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit) is the one I am using right now:

MDN option: [MDN option reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

W3 innerHTML: [Inner HTML reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)

When I add with inner HTML or DOM methods, with the following page, we see the last data list is not showing anything, and the standard says option should only hold text content.
Inner html always removes the content inside a tag.

**Why option is holding strong tag, if it does not apply to the standard?**

**Why working with options from a data list is different than working with the select?**

[Example in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juan_garcia/0y2c1ue9/1/)

```
<!doctype>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      select { display: block }
      datalist { display: block}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Using DOM methods in Select</h2>
    <p id="dom-methods-ul"></p>
    <h2 style="color:red;">Using innerHTML in Select</h2>
    <p id="inner-html-ul"></p>
    <h2>Using DOM methods in DataList</h2>
    <p id="dom-methods-dl"></p>
    <h2 style="color:red;">Using innerHTML in DataList</h2>
    <p id="inner-html-dl"></p>

    <script>
      function createOptions(withDOM, withInnerHTML, type) {
        // using DOM methods:
        var select = document.createElement(type),
            option = document.createElement('option'),
            strong = document.createElement('strong'),
            exampleHTML = '<' + type + '><option><strong>Hello</strong></option></' + type + '>';

        strong.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello'));
        option.appendChild(strong);
        select.appendChild(option);
        withDOM.appendChild(select);
        withDOM.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(select.innerHTML)
        );

        // using innerHTML
        withInnerHTML.innerHTML = exampleHTML;
        withInnerHTML.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(withInnerHTML.innerHTML)
        )
      }
      createOptions(document.getElementById('dom-methods-ul'), document.getElementById('inner-html-ul'), 'select');
      createOptions(document.getElementById('dom-methods-dl'), document.getElementById('inner-html-dl'), 'datalist');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better question might be why is there a strong tag there in the first place? Just because spec says it shouldn't be there...doesn't mean all browsers will treat it the same if it is. Really not sure what you are expecting here

Comment: I just want to know why if it is not supported to add other tags inside an option, we see it is something we can do freely and why it is different for a select than a datalist. We see option is the same standard for data list and select

Comment: No idea...and that would be a question of browser vendors and I doubt they all do manage it the same. Chaulk it up to an imperfect world. Seems too trivial to put much effort into worrying about it

Comment: I agree :) @charlietfl this is just a question I had some time ago, but I could not answer, just because it is something I can not answer I posted it to see if I am missing something, trivial or not as a learning matter.

Comment: Browsers have fully defined behaviour for many forms of invalid HTML. This is just one small example. Ever since XHTML and the DOM API were invented, it's been impossible for browsers to rely on the HTML parser to protect against violations to the HTML content model, so browsers use other strategies to handle them. But the select element pre-dates that, and HTML parsers remain backward compatible with their early behaviour.

Comment: @Alohci sounds like you are right if you can make an answer with some reference I can read about it, I would be glad